# I cannot use a given symbol in the char type, as a mathematical symbol

Tags: php

```
$a=rand(1, 10);
$b=rand(1, 11);
$belgilar = ['+', '-', '*'];
$belgi = $belgilar[rand(0, 2)];
$masala = $a." ".$belgi." ". $b." = ";
echo $masala;
$c = ($a.($belgi).$b);
echo $c;
```

(the return: 4 - 3 = 4-3)::but the answer should not be so. It should give me a result of 4-3 that is 1.

Comment: `.` is for string concatenation. You need to run that snippet/formula as code to be evaluated and then calculated. One way to do this would be https://3v4l.org/9CZpR

Comment: try eval("return $a $operator $b;");

Comment: @StefanAvramovic I'd discourage that. As manual states `Its use thus is discouraged. If you have carefully verified that there is no other option than to use this construct`. Very rarely if every should eval be used. I've never had a reason to use eval since PHP 4.

Comment: (With dup suggestion I don't recommend `eval` usage. See all other usages and notes of `eval` dangers)

Comment: In case it's not clear, adding brackets doesn't make any difference here: `$c = ($a.($belgi).$b);` just means the same thing as `$c = $a . $belgi . $b;`

Comment: Thank you, @Stefan Avramovich.   eval("return $a $operator $b;");  => this code worked.